# how to Execute PhantomJS from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

I want to execute PhantomJS from PHP on localhost.

Can any body explain how to execute PhantomJS from PHP and what package I should download  from phantomjs.org?

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/jonnyw/php-phantomjs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651320/starting-phantomjs-server-from-php-and-waiting-for-its-response (google for "phantomjs php" gives lots of good hits, some even at stackoverflow)

Comment: i cant run php phantomjs script on my local and it's make some error that i dont know whay they happen ... i test some this script from git

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- download the [PhantomJS binary](http://phantomjs.org/download.html), upload it somewhere and make it executable (`chmod +x`)
- if you are going to make screenshots, setup [fontconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig) (this is pretty specific to my config but the goal is to make sure to have at least some fonts on your system)
- run the following in PHP:
  `$response = exec('/path/to/phantomjs myscript.js');`

Comment: thanx a lot for answer .
im try to use it at localhost in windows 7 and xampp server . 
how i make it executable? and what package i should to download ? windows or linux version ?

Comment: For anybody having issues with this solution, by following [this answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phantomjs/s8RS-Glf7fg/z82YTZpWaycJ) I managed to successfully call my Phantom script from PHP.

Comment: @Benjy I tried this `$response = exec('/phantom/phantomjs myscript.js');  exec("phantom/bin/phantomjs phantom/examples/hello.js", $response); (replace " with normal ticks) 
echo implode("<br>", $response);` but nothing at all is echoed, why is this? Everything  has proper permissions, and it executes with no issue through SSH

Comment: how to make Phantomjs executable by using chmod +x... i try to run chmod +x command in command prompt but it gives error 'can't open chmod'

Answer (score 11):

There's actually a library called [*PHP PhantomJS*](http://phantomjs.org/), intended to make this easier for you!

> PHP PhantomJS is a flexible PHP library to load pages through the
>   PhantomJS headless browser and return the page response. It is handy
>   for testing websites that demand javascript support and also supports
>   screen captures.
>
> [**Full documentation**](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/)

Feature list :

> - Load webpages through the PhantomJS headless browser
> - View detailed response data including page content, headers, status code etc.
> - Handle redirects
> - View javascript console errors
> - View detailed PhantomJS debugged information
> - Save screen captures to local disk
> - Set viewport size
> - Define screen capture x, y, width and height parameters
> - Delay page rendering for a specified time
> - Execute PhantomJS with command line options
> - Easily build and run custom PhantomJS scripts

Make sure, though, that your version of *PhantomJS* is compatible with your version of *PHP PhantomJS*:

> **Please Note:** Version 4.0 of this library is currently waiting on an
>   unresolved issue with PhantomJS 2.0.

Comment: What's the unresolved issue, is it that it's ridiculously slow to open webpages post 1.9?

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/q/61983687/3170029 possible using **PHP PhantomJS**?

Answer (score 4):

I recently published a project that gives PHP access to a browser. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS. Under the hood it relies on PhantomJS.

After downloading and setup you would simply use the following code:

```
$myUrl          = "http://www.example.com";
$windowObj      = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getBrowser('phantomjs')->getNewWindow($myUrl);

//now you can either retrive the DOM and parse it, like this:
$domData    = $windowObj->getDom();

//or take screen shots
$imageData    = $windowObj->screenshot();

//or use the mouse to click buttons:
$windowObj->mouseEventOnElement("[id=searchInput]", 'leftclick');

//or type with the keyboard :
$windowObj->sendKeyPresses("my search words");

//or load and execute custom javascript, fill forms etc, etc.
```

Comment: I tried MTS in windows 10 and it doesn't work: "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: MTS\Common\Devices\Actions\Local\Host\OperatingSystem::execute>> Could not determine OS Architecture in..."

Comment: @Tarilonte SO is not the right venue for troubleshooting, please head over to https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS/issues and open a new issue.