# How can I download a _rendered_ web page using PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom, render

I know I can use something like `file_get_contents` to save a web page's source locally, and I know how to manipulate the text of it. But what if the web page has JavaScript that dynamically generates content? How can I download the fully rendered page source?

Comment: PhantomJS is a good choice, and is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data through a rendering engine. The simplest option is to programmatically control a web browser. Libraries that will help you do that include [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and [php-phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202407/how-to-execute-phantomjs-from-php).