# Execute PhantomJs script from PHP on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, phantomjs

I am trying to run PhantomJS from a PHP script using 
`exec('/path/to/phantomjs/phantonjs --version');`
This line works fine from the CLI but does not work at all from my PHP script.

I have searched around for a fix and found this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202407/how-to-execute-phantomjs-from-php) and read something about permissions that can be the problem. I have try all these fixes and still, PhantomJS does not launch.

I'm desperate at this point, can someone help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting that to output something? You need to `echo` the returned value.

Comment: I have echoed it and even tried adding an output array as second parameter for exec but the command simply does not run. :(

Comment: Can you create a minimum version of your script that doesn't work, and post that? Have you been able to get `exec` to work using the interactive interpreter using `php -a`?

Comment: I have PhantomJS in `/usr/local/bin`. The binary is executable and I have both permissions and ownership.

I use a script as simple as `$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/phantomjs --version';`

This obviously works flawlessly from the CLI but when called from PHP with: 

`$response = exec($cmd, $out, $status) ;`

The status returns `true` meaning the command was not executed and both `$response` and `$out` are empty. Not `null` but respectively an empty string and an array of strings with one empty string element.

Comment: Maybe something in php.ini is preventing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your path looks wrong in the `exec` command, it uses phanto**n**js where I'd expect it to be phantomjs. Might that be the problem?

Comment: Hello @daphtdazz and thanks for your answer.
I have tried it and still it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. PhantomJS required som libraries that were not found in my Xampp packages and was just failing silently and updating the logs. So I just install the standalone PHP and Apache services and everything worked fine.