# i'm unable to run phantomjs in laravel using exec

Tags: php, phantomjs, laravel-5.4, casperjs

Why i'm unable to `execute` `phantomjs` form `exec` in `laravel 5.4`

**the step i have followed**

1. downloaded `phantomjs` from http://phantomjs.org/ and placed inside root of `project` **(laravel root)**
2. placed script inside `public/js/phantom.js`

**i did something like this in laravel**

```
Route::get('phantomjs',function(){


  $basePath = base_path();

  $jsPath = $basePath.'\\public\\phantom.js';

  $phantom = $basePath.'\\phantomjs.exe';

  $response = exec("$phantom $jsPath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202407/how-to-execute-phantomjs-from-php stack.pdf");

 dd($response);  

});
```

**here is my `phantom.js script`**

```
var page = require( 'webpage' ).create(),
    system = require('system');

/**
 * Check for required parameters
 */
if ( system.args.length < 3 ) {
  console.log( 'Usage: report.js <some URL> <output path/filename>' );
  phantom.exit();
}

/**
 * Grab the page and output it to specified target
 */
page.open( system.args[ 1 ], function( status ) {

       window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
       if ( status === "success" ) {
          //page.render( 'example22.pdf');
          page.render( system.args[ 2 ] );
        }
            phantom.exit();
        }, 12000);
} );
```

**Here is my project (you can downoload):**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1abkqlzyqg1u6ae/phantom.zip?dl=0

(after download) please visit this url =>

> localhost:8000/phantomjs

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: No one is going to download your project and execute it. Explain the issue you are getting, what error messages. If there's an expected output, post your output vs what you expected

Comment: yeh thats correct, but i'm unable to execute the command `exec()` because of path mismatch

Comment: Post the exact error response

Comment: no error at all i want to generate pdf with `phantomjs`

Comment: `i'm unable to execute the command exec() because of path mismatch` How do you know there's a path mismatch then?

Comment: PDF is not generating, thats how i can say

Comment: i have installed `phantomjs` globally. i'm able to generate pdf using this command in command prompt `$ phantomjs report2.js http://s.codepen.io/amcharts/
      debug/cd2e8ce27e3a96f43bb79d5d23722d11 report3.pdf`